# Certificate based Azure VPN Connection - How Does it work?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-vpn

I followed this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps#Certificates to create a VPN in Azure. So,

1. I created a root certificate and uploaded to management portal.
2. Used PS script to create the VPN
3. Created client certificate and installed the VPN Client package.

My VPN is working as expected. My question is now can I delete this certificate from management store now ? Is it must to upload the certificate to management store to create this VPN ? How does the authentication works in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is now can I delete this certificate from management store
>   now ?

By default, we **can't** delete this certificate.

> Is it must to upload the certificate to management store to create
>   this VPN ?

Yes, we have to upload the certificate to it, it is a by design behavior.
We can publish our public certificate to Internet, we only should keep the private certificate.

> How does the authentication works in this case ?

Here a blog about how does certificate-based authentication work, please refer to [this link](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2226498/infrastructure-management/simply-put-how-does-certificate-based-authentication-work.html).

Comment: Link provided by you doesn't talk exactly about how the authentication works for azure vNet. I did an experiment and manually deleted the certificate from azure certificate management store. Still I am able to connect to VPN, Now this has become even more complicated to understand.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot delete the root certificate that you uploaded to Azure. It is used to authenticate the certificates presented by the connecting clients.